# How can I specify arguments by column numbers in bwplot?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

**This works.**

```
ok <- function(data)
{
    lattice:::bwplot(size ~ mxPH, data=data)
}

> ok(algae)
## no error
```

[image]

**I'd like to specify *size* and *mxPH* by its column numbers. However, the following didn't work.**

**1st attempt**

```
aa <- function(data, n1, n2)
{
    names <- names(data) 
    lattice:::bwplot(names[n1] ~ names[n2], data=data)
} 

> aa(algae,2,4)
Warning message:
In function (x, y, box.ratio = 1, box.width = box.ratio/(1 + box.ratio),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

[image]

**2nd Attempt (small modification to the 1st one)**

```
bb <- function(data, n1, n2) 
{       
    names <- factor(names(data))
    lattice:::bwplot(names[n1] ~ names[n2], data=data)
} 

> bb(algae,2,4)
## no error
```

[image]

**3rd Attempt (small modification to the 2nd one)**

```
cc <- function(data, n1, n2)
{   
    names <- factor(names(data))
    lattice:::bwplot(deparse(substitute(names[n1])) ~ deparse(substitute(names[n2])), data=data)
}

> cc(algae,2,4)
Warning message:
In function (x, y, box.ratio = 1, box.width = box.ratio/(1 + box.ratio),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```
algae <- utils:::read.table('http://www.liaad.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/DataSets/Analysis.txt',
         header=F,
         dec='.',
         col.names=c('season','size','speed','mxPH','mnO2','Cl','NO3','NH4','oPO4','PO4','Chla','a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7'),
         na.strings=c('XXXXXXX'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(lattice)
bwplot.column <- function(data, n1, n2, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, ...)
{
  if (is.null(ylab)) {
    ylab <- names(data)[n1]
  }

  if (is.null(xlab)) {
    xlab <- names(data)[n2]
  }

  bwplot(data[,n1] ~ data[,n2], xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, data = data, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the specific columns as Michael demonstrates, or you can also paste the formula together manually:

```
fun <- function(dat,n1,n2){
    nms <- colnames(dat)
    f <- as.formula(paste(nms[n1],"~",nms[n2]))
    bwplot(f,data = dat)
}

fun(algae,2,4)
```